# main thread does not wait for CompletableFuture.runAsync() and returned the response

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

I have a function which has a invoke method , which internally calls an soap API ,
and it's taking like 22 seconds to execute , there are few other methods also in code ,
So totally deleteSoemthing()(code below) method takes like 24 seconds ,

now , i tried running the time taking method in a separate thread ,
So my assumption was even though its separate thread , it will just be optimize to 2 seconds because it was taking 22 seconds from total 24 seconds.

so instead of 24 seconds it might take 22 seconds because its running parallel.

but when i run this , through a postman , it takes only 2 seconds to execute , i mean the response is returned in 2 seconds. and the separate thread is keep running(when i check through debug).

So , my doubt is , does main thread does not wait for this task to complete and send the response back .
or its just send the response and keep running the async task in background

```
void deleteSomething(){

CompletableFuture<Void> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    invoke("invoking a soap API"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

//some other code

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the main thread (request) to process "some other code" and "invoke SOAP API" parallely and then combine and return the response to the end-user, then this wont work.

When we create a CompletableFuture instance, it spins off the computation in another thread and returns the Future immediately. If you need to block the result, then you need to call the *get* method on it. However this process will still take 22+2 = 24 secs to return the response.

To run the two tasks parallely, you should created two **Callable**(s) and submit them to **ExecutorService**

eg.

```
  public void deleteSomething(){
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    Collection<Callable<Void>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
    callables.add(() -> doSomeOtherTask());
    callables.add(() -> invokeSoapApi());
    try {
      List<Future<Void>> taskFutureList = executorService.invokeAll(callables);
      taskFutureList.get(0).get();
      taskFutureList.get(1).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      //error
    }
  }

  public Void doSomeOtherTask() {
    //some other code
    return null;
  }

  public Void invokeSoapApi() {
    //soap api call
    return null;
  }
```

Please note that thread pool should be created at the application startup.
So if you actually wish to use it, then you should have "executorService" defined as instance variable. eg.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  ...
  ...
  private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
  ...
  ...
  //your methods
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply , So i actually don't need the result of "invoke SOAP API" in response , dont want to combine , just want to run it like on background . So , i think in this case completableFuture will work fine for me, just wanted to know , that by default in will not wait for the ConpletableFuture Response , like you said .So, in case of callables in you example .. it'll combine and send the response , may be take like 22 seconds instead of 24  , right?

Comment: yes ..correct. unless you do a "get" on a future, it will keep running on the other thread. "get" is the blocking call, which suspends current thread until that other thread returns.

Comment: When you use [`invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)), it will already wait until all specified jobs have been completed, regardless of whether you call `get` afterwards or not. `ExecutorService` and `CompletableFuture` are not contradictions. E.g., you can use `ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); CompletableFuture<Void> job1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> …, es), job2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> …, es); job1.join(); job2.join();`.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour of `CompletableFuture`, if you checked the documentation it says -

```
/**
 * Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed
 * by a task running in the ForkJoinPool#commonPool() after
 * it runs the given action.
 *
 * @param runnable the action to run before completing the
 * returned CompletableFuture
 * @return the new CompletableFuture
 */
```

You can use blocking Future.get() to achieve what you want (as shown below)

```
void deleteSomething(){
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
        invoke("Invoking soap API");
        return null;
    });
    
    //some other code

    future.get();
}
```

Creation of Thread pool in a method is not advisable as there is overhead associated with thread creation. Ideally, Thread pool should be created at the application startup.

Comment: you are correct regarding "Thread pool should be created at the application startup." Ideally the "executorService" should have been an instance variable of the enclosing class. But here since i dont have that , i gave example . I should mention this ..

Comment: Hi , thanks , actually i don't have to use future.get() , as i just wanted to run that invoke method in background , not needed in response , so it will work fine i guess , i was just wondering about completableFuture behaviour.with main thread.

Comment: `CompletableFuture` implements `Future`, hence, it also has a `get()` method. No need to rewrite the entire code.

Comment: Hi @Holger, yes agree. But the question is does OP needs to use `CompletableFuture` in first place as his need is to more of a wait for another task to finish.